# How to change property path name in JsonPatchDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger

I am using JsonPatchDocument as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProductPatch([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Product> request)
```

Now request body is:

```
{
  "path": "string",
  "value" "string"
}
```

I want to change "path" name to "fieldToChange" name but still using JsonPatchDocument object. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the name "Path" comes from specification https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902
and can't be changed.

moreover why do want to change which is part of standard. eventually whoever calls your api will also be using standard way of creating JsonPatch object, so they will also have to change which in my opinion is unnecessary.